# How to get the buffer number of `:bn`?

Tags: vimscript

As title. When running `:bn` the current buffer will be switched to the next buffer. I want to get the buffer number of this buffer without changing the current buffer(or, at least, can switch back to the starting buffer)

Answer (score 1):

I can't fint a build-in solution for this, here is a function using [getbufinfo()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getbufinfo%28%29) that does not need to actually change buffers:

```
function! Next_buf()
    let l:bufs = getbufinfo({'buflisted': 1}

    let l:later = filter(l:bufs), 'v:val.bufnr > ' . bufnr())

    if len(l:later) > 0
        return l:later[0].bufnr
    else
        return l:bufs[0].bufnr
    endif
endfunction
```

I emulated the behavior of `:bn` of wrapping around at the end and filtering out hidden buffers.

Comment: But does the buffer with `bufnr()` closest to the current one really the next buffer?

Comment: @Kindred I’m not sure I understand your question. This function should behave the same as `:bn`, that is: return the number of the next visible buffer if any, or the first one otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the naive way works: (answer in Lua)

```lua
vim.cmd('bn')
local buf_right = vim.fn.bufnr()
vim.cmd('bp')
```